# Connect to DB mysql with Bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

I cant find the command in bash that open the connection to mysql and then I could enter user and password and send query.

In Perl its something like this:

```
use DBI;
$myConnection = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:DBNAME:localhost", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
```

Maybe someone can advise?

Comment: use the ``mysql`` command line tool.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like that.

```
query="example"
mysql -u username -p password mysql -e "$query";
```

Src: MySql documentation.

Hope have been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use a [hereoc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) :

```
mysql -u  username -p password mysql <<-EOF
query1;
query2;
.
.
EOF
```